How do i bind mutliple IP addresses to port 8080 in trafficserver file records.config. im using version 9.1.1
How do i bind multiple IP addresses to port 8080 in trafficserver file records.config. Im using version 9.1.1
so far i have tried:
CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING "*:8080"

#CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 
"8080:ip=10.120.36.138:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.0.138:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.32:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.33:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.34:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.35:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.36:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.37:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.38:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.38:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.39:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.40:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.41:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.42:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.43:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.44:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.45:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.46:proto=http, 
 8080:ip=10.120.37.47:proto=http"

#CONFIG proxy.config.http.server_ports STRING 
"8080,10.120.36.138:8080,10.120.0.138:8080,10.120.37.32:8080"

and none of them work. can you help?

I'd think you'd use proxy.local.incoming_ip_to_bind if you wanted to bind specific IPs.
